# Can you reset the SMC an all Mac laptops by pressing power for 5 seconds after disconnecting the battery?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've always had this doubt and some clarification would be very welcome.  On Mac notebooks with non-removable battery (such as the MacBook Pro 2014), is the SMC reset by disconnecting the battery and pressing power for 5 second as is done on older Macs with removable batteries (such as in cases where Alt or Command keys are not working).

Here's the Apple article on SMC reset:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

Answer (score 2):

No, on Mac notebooks with non-removable batteries you *"press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds"*, exactly like stated in the support article you linked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've modified my question, I meant in cases in which any of the SMC buttons isn't working.

Comment: I'm a technician and I'm resetting SMCs every day, when the keyboard isn't working, we usually press the power button for 5 seconds after disconnecting the battery as was done in old Macs.  I can't be sure if this is really doing anything, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: There are anecdotal references around the web from technicians that the old "disconnect the battery and hold power for 5 seconds" works on newer Macbooks, the key combo was added and began to be recommended because disconnecting the battery on newer models is nowhere near as easy and not intended to be done by users. It doesn't mean it doesn't work, though, only that Apple doesn't tell you it still works because the batteries are much less easily accessible. IE: https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/does-the-smc-and-pram-nvram-get-reset-when-you-disconnect-the-battery-in-a-macbook.399328/